# How to get the Config Blob Uri parameter from restored VHD from Azure Recovery Services Vault in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

Currently, I am working in a Powershell to restore the VHD file from a Virtual Machine which is being backed up by Azure Recovery Services Vault.

That being said, my difficulty is how do I get the **Config Blob Uri** parameter after restoring the VHD using Powershell? Even using `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJobDetails -Job $restoreJob` I don't see any option that provides this information.

As you can see in the image below, the Azure Portal shows the Config Blob Uri parameter

[image: Config Blob Uri from Azure Portal]

Once the Powershell completes the restore, then I'd like to retrieve the Config Blob Uri to perform a VM creation based on that specific VHD file, however, without such information, I have to get it manually.

Is there any possibility to get it directly from Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#get restore job detail
$details = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJobDetails -Job $restorejob
#restored disk properties
$properties = $details.properties
$storageAccountName = $properties["Target Storage Account Name"]
$containerName = $properties["Config Blob Container Name"]
$blobName = $properties["Config Blob Name"]
#Set the Azure storage context and restore the JSON configuration file
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$destination_path = "C:\temp\vmconfig.json"
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Destination $destination_path
$obj = ((Get-Content -Path $destination_path -Raw -Encoding Unicode)).TrimEnd([char]0x00) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This will download config json file to $destination_path and you can reference your that file when building your VM.

More details at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#restore-an-azure-vm

Also, if you know your Storage Account Name, you can retrieve config uri from there:

```
$storageAccountName = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).StorageAccountName
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$storageContainerName = (Get-AzureStorageContainer).Name
$configBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $storageContainerName  | where {$_.Name -match "json"}
$configName = $configBlob.Name 
$configURI = "https://$storageAccountname.blob.core.windows.net/$storageContainerName/$configName"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, except for the JSON file, because now getting "Config Blob Container Name", then I will be able to build the URI for later restore!